# Get app Roles with bearer token via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use the bearer token from the user to be sent to my api via a authorization header and then sent to graph api to return back if my app.admin role is applied to that user or not. What request could i send the the Microsoft graph api to receive if i have the proper app role.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the Graph API doesn't return bearer tokens, you need to request one from the **Microsoft identity platform** endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` Full details can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I currently am using the Microsoft identity platform to authenticate my users on my front end, but i would like to take that bearer token and verify the user has the claims. The reason why i wanted to use the graph api to verify the roles vs just taking them from the bearer token is to verify that the bearer token is legitimate and not created by a third party